# How to run EXtjs in production without Ext.Loader

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have developed an app using Extjs 4.2 and Geoext2-2.0. I have three files for my app as following:

```
index.html
app.js
loader.js
```

I have read that when moving from development to production is not recommended to use the Ext.Loader.
My question is quite simple. How do I do this? Right now my loader file contains this:

```
`Ext.Loader.setConfig ({
  enabled : true,
  disableCaching : false,
  paths : {
    GeoExt : "../geoext2-2.0.0/src/GeoExt",
    Ext : "../ext-4.2.1.883/src"
  }
 });
```

I call this file inside my index.html file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
```

If I comment this line then my app won't initiate. What am I missing here?

Thanks
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Sencha Cmd](https://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) to build a single javascript file containing everything your web app needs.

A build script might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export EXTJS_SRC=path/to/ext-4.2/src
export GEOEXT_SRC=path/to/geoext/src
export MY_APP=/path/to/my/app

sencha compile \
  --debug \
  -classpath $EXTJS_SRC,$GEOEXT_SRC,$MY_APP/src \
  concat -output-file $MY_APP/bin/MyApp.js
```

Comment: What if I haven't used the Sencha Cmd?

Comment: No problem - you can use cmd to compile apps even if you didn't create the project with it (which is exactly what I've always done).

Comment: Ok. I will try this. One last question. I haven't followed 100% the folder (app) structures suggested in the tutorials. Will this cause problems when compiling using sencha cmd? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't do - if the loader can find your js files cmd will too, so long as the classpath you pass to cmd is right